# Многопоточность java, ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, android-studio, многопоточность

Как выполнить какое-либо действие, допустим, через 5 секунд? Создал поток, он отчасти помогает, но после него нет тех действий, что прописаны в теле. И можете посоветовать как лучше обращаться с потоками? Спасибо.

```
    button.setEnabled(false);

    final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    service.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: не понятно, что не так...

Comment: Как я понимаю, в run нужно писать код, который выполнится по истечению времени? Пробовал вызвать toast - не работает. Enabled true для кнопки - отчасти работает (нужно нажать на кнопку повторно, тогда можно увидеть, что она становится доступной, а сама почему-то не может такого)

Comment: Во-первых, библиотеки графического интерфейса, включая библиотеку интерфейса Android, не являются потокобезопасными, а потому вы не можете из потока манипулировать компонентами интерфейса. Во-вторых, в API Android есть собственные средства управления потоками, стоит предпочесть их использованию механизмов стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Так а какая задача? Может проще использовать что-то типа postDelayed?